# MySQL Select Dates within Calendar week

Tags: mysql

I want to select all data from a table where a `last_update` field is 'this week'.  So between the previous Sunday, and the upcoming Saturday.

I found this answer that finds dates LAST Week, but I can't quite figure out how to tailor it for what I need, which is this calendar week.

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE last_update >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND last_update < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer on this one:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE last_update >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
AND last_update <= curdate() + INTERVAL 7 DAY - DAYOFWEEK(curdate())
```

Comment: Yep: That did the trick! Thanks for answering your own question. :-)